# How to negate marked subexpressions with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, regex-negation

Suppose I have an expression such as `egrep "^b([aeuio])\1$"`
that will match a 3 letter word starting with b folowed by a vowal and then the same vowal again. How do I negate the marked subexpression so that the first vowal is followed by any character that is not the first vowal.

Comment: Provide examples of what you want to match or not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so that the first vowel is followed by any character that is not the
>   first vowel

Use the following approach:

```
echo "bay" | grep -P '^b([aeuio])(?!\1).$'
```

The output(as a match):

```
bay
```

---

`-P` option, allows Perl compatible regular expresssions

`(?!\1)` - lookahead negative assertion, assures that *the first vowel* is not followed by itself

---

While `echo "baa" | grep -P '^b([aeuio])(?!\1).$'` won't give a match

Comment: Worked perfectly. But so I need Perl regex option to achieve this?

Comment: @Tsui, yes, to apply such things as lookahead/lookbehind assertions you'll need perl regex

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the standard `grep` matching process.  List the things you wish to grep via `grep`, piped to filter the things you wish to miss via `grep -v`.  So the result would be:

```
egrep "^b([aeuio]).$" | egrep -v "^b([aeuio])\1$"
```